# how to sort the child nodes of treeView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview, custom-compare

I want to sort a given TreeView child nodes in alphabetical order.

Suppose my tree View is like this:

- firstNode1

  - secondNode1
  - thirdNode1
  - thirdNode2
  - thirdNode3
    ...
- firstNode2

  - secondNode1
  - thirdNode1
  - thirdNode2
  - thirdNode3
    ...

I want to sort the nodes in secondNodes of every firstNode.

How can I do it? - I have red about Custom Comparer but cant understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: We also need a [mcve] that shows your effort so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a **normal alphabetical** sort simply call the built-in sort:

```
treeView1.Sort();
```

and you are good.

But sometimes this is not good enough. Then you need to write a **custom sorter**. This is really simple; all it needs to provide is an `int` for the result of `<`, `==` or `>`, i.e. return `-1`, `0` or `1` respectively.  Often the built-in comparers will do after massaging the data a bit..

Here is an example of a custom sorter. This is a simple class implementing the `IComparer` interface, which has just one method..

---

It prepares the two node texts for my custom comparison before calling the regular string `Compare` method.

The preparation inserts a large number of zeroes to pad a trailing number to a constant length.

It is just an example but will sort e.g. the default names from the designer numerically/chronologically.

---

```
public class NodeSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public NodeSorter() { }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TreeNode tx = x as TreeNode;
        TreeNode ty = y as TreeNode;

        string s1 = tx.Text;
        while (s1.Length > 0 && Char.IsDigit(s1.Last())) s1 = s1.TrimEnd(s1.Last());
        s1 = s1 + tx.Text.Substring(s1.Length).PadLeft(12, '0');

        string s2 = tx.Text;
        while (s2.Length > 0 && Char.IsDigit(s2.Last())) s2 = s2.TrimEnd(s2.Last());
        s2 = s2 + ty.Text.Substring(s2.Length).PadLeft(12, '0');

        return string.Compare(s1, s2);
    }
}
```

You call it by assigning it and then calling sort:

```
treeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = new NodeSorter();
treeView1.Sort();
```

Result:

[image][image][image]

This is a slightly modified version of the [MSDN TreeNodeSorter example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter(v=vs.110).aspx). Besides the changed logic do note:

- The example is **old** and doesn't qualify the `IComparer` interface properly. With the advent of **generics** we usually have a `using System.Collections.Generic;` clause and this will **hide** the non-generic `IComparer` interface, leading to compiler errors, complaining about the missing type arguments.

Adding the qualification takes care of that..:

```
public class NodeSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
```